# Floating divs in parents with different z-index affect on each other

Tags: css-float, z-index

The layout is quite simple.

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div1-child">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div id="div2-child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Both childs float right and 100% height of their parents. But the first child is a bit lower, so the second `div` is pushed left to get the free room for the first. I need `div2-child` to overlap `div1-child`. But if I set different `z-index` to `div1` and `div2`, `div1-child` just being overlapped by `div2` still affecting on `div2-child`.

I need this to be explained.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Js5B/).

Answer (score 0):

If you give position relative to parent than you have to play second child dive with position absolute.

if you are agree with position absolute with second div child than your working demo is below

jsfiddle.net/2Js5B/2/